# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception error when I run the app

Tags: android-studio, flutter, ide

I started working with a flutter project, and as a beginner, I tried to run the default code given by the flutter team. But I keep getting the error as given below.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform artifact 'core.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-res}.
> > Execution failed for AarTransform: C:\Users\krish.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a528b13ac93e64cafa3d0480e2c93207\core-1.1.0.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform artifact 'core.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-res}.
> > Execution failed for AarTransform: C:\Users\krish.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a528b13ac93e64cafa3d0480e2c93207\core-1.1.0.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform artifact 'core.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-res}.
> > Execution failed for AarTransform: C:\Users\krish.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a528b13ac93e64cafa3d0480e2c93207\core-1.1.0.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform artifact 'core.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-res}.
> > Execution failed for AarTransform: C:\Users\krish.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a528b13ac93e64cafa3d0480e2c93207\core-1.1.0.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform artifact 'core.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-res}.
> > Execution failed for AarTransform: C:\Users\krish.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a528b13ac93e64cafa3d0480e2c93207\core-1.1.0.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 7s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with
> exit code 1

It would be of great help if you could help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which sdk version are you using ?

Comment: I am using flutter windows 1.22.5-stable

Comment: And android gradle version ?

Comment: I am using gradle-5.6.2